# How to remove status bar from Modal ViewController in iOS App

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am working on a Children's book app for iPad and my app opens up an Modal Window to be able to select Male or Female Narrator. I am unable to remove the status bar from the Modal Window. Pls. see attached screenshot (highlighted in yellow color). Also, how do I make the window look pretty or make is transparent as it doesn't look too appealing at the moment?

[image]

Here is the code logic to open the ModalViewController inside my Main Controller:

```
-(IBAction)appLinkGet{
    [self loadSetupModalView];   
}

-(void)loadSetupModalView{
    NSLog(@"ChildrenBookViewController ==> loadSetupModalView::");

    // Create a Navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:self.setupViewController];
    //RESIZE THE MODAL VIEW
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    navController.view.superview.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;    
    navController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(
                                                    navController.view.superview.frame.origin.x,
                                                    navController.view.superview.frame.origin.y,
                                                    540.0f,
                                                    400.0f
                                                    );
    //navController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
    [navController release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this method:

```
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will try that and will let you know.